# Webforms: Redirect to home page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to redirect the user to the home page without actually having to reference the static page name like this:

```
context.Response.Redirect("home.aspx", false);
```

Instead I'd like to do something like:

```
context.Response.Redirect("/", false);
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways.

1. rename your `home.aspx` to `default.aspx` because this is the default setting inside the web server for the homepage
2. You have to set the `home.aspx` as your homepage inside your webserver. E.g. if you hosting online and have the cPanel available you can do this there.

Comment: And then I would still use context.Response.Redirect("default.aspx", false) ?

Comment: No, you can use context.Response.Redirect("/", false); Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Or another solution could be to use routing:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx

You could setup a route for the mapping "/" to the home.aspx page, something like:

routes.MapPageRoute("HomeRoute",
    "/",
    "~/home.aspx");